# How to extract a column from a dataframe and make a boxplot from it?

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I have a dataframe, which I have imported from a Stata database, and I have renamed its columns, and I have tried to make a boxplot from one of the columns(e.g 'Peso') but when I plot it, the graph displays all the dataframe. How could I extract the column and plot it?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_stata('Datos Peso Altura Genero.dta')
datos=df.rename(columns={'var1':'Sujeto','var2':'Peso','var3':'Altura','var4':'Género'})

    Sujeto  Peso  Altura Género
0        1    50     154      M
1        2    56     152      H
2        3    58     161      M
3        4    59     160      M
4        5    60     167      H
5        6    61     165      M
6        7    63     169      M
7        8    65     158      M
8        9    67     155      M
9       10    72     169      H
10      11    75     170      H
11      12    77     178      H
12      13    78     180      H
13      14    80     175      M
14      15    84     179      H

datos.boxplot(column=['Peso'])
plt.title('Ejemplo peso')
plt.ylabel('Peso (kg)')
plt.show()
```

I hope I have made myself clear, and thank you for your answers.

Comment: Your code already draws a graph with only the 'Peso' column. The question and the code match.

Comment: I have another question. I want to boxplot the same Peso column but sorting it by the column Género, so I would get two boxplots, Peso for M and Peso for H. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify `by=['Género']`, you will get a box plot with H and M. I've commented out the title specification as it will automatically display the title. See [this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html?highlight=boxplot#pandas.DataFrame.boxplot) for details.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io

data = '''
 Sujeto Peso Altura Género
0 1 50 154 M
1 2 56 152 H
2 3 58 161 M
3 4 59 160 M
4 5 60 167 H
5 6 61 165 M
6 7 63 169 M
7 8 65 158 M
8 9 67 155 M
9 10 72 169 H
10 11 75 170 H
11 12 77 178 H
12 13 78 180 H
13 14 80 175 M
14 15 84 179 H
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

# df=pd.read_stata('Datos Peso Altura Genero.dta')
datos = df.rename(columns={'var1':'Sujeto','var2':'Peso','var3':'Altura','var4':'Género'})

datos.boxplot(column=['Peso'], by=['Género'])

# plt.title('Ejemplo peso')
plt.ylabel('Peso (kg)')
plt.show()
```

[image]